# How to add dashboard in Lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dashboard

We want to add dashboard in Lightning component. Which will be updated every time respective records gets updated. Is there any option to add standard Lightning dashboard in Lightning component or VF page.

Answer (score 1):

As of now , there is no standard functionality for adding a dashboard.